# How to use C# to setup UI with XAML Grid

Tags: c#, xaml

Context: Windows 8.1 windows store app codeing in C# and XAML. Using Visual Studio Express 2013.

Hi, I've been trying to code XAML app for windows store, but I just can't seem to linking the XAML control (`Page`, `Grid`, `ContentPresenter`, or whatever) to the c# code properly.

This has caused much frustration and I can't seem to find anything that answers this problem explicitly and directly.

So I'm asking for help with a very specific context: 
I'm trying to build the xaml UI in c# to be executed when the app starts, but I can't seem to reference the control properly to GIVE my UI, or the line execution order is wrong, I just don't know.

I have a `Page` in my Main.xaml code:

```
<Page
x:Class="App4.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App4"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
>

<Grid x:Name="pgMain" 
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    >
</Grid>
```

I tried alternating `x:Name` with `Name` too...

Anyway, the C# code is this part, and here I am trying to set the `Grid` "pgMain" to the Grid object I create using my custom method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace App4 {
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage() {
            //this right here. is the line order wrong?  Tried that. 
            //Is it impossible to do what I want before/after InitializeComponent? 
            //If so, then is there another way to achieve this???
            pgMain = buildUIGrid(); 

            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Grid buildUIGrid() {
            Grid g = new Grid();

            int[] dimensions = { 3, 3 };//grid is 3 by 3

            //setup grid definitions
            for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
                g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star) });
            for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[1]; i++)
                g.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star) });
            //setup testing textboxes
            for (int i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++) { 
                for (int j = 0; j < dimensions[1]; j++){
                    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                    tb.Text = "test at col "+i+", row "+j;
                    Grid.SetColumn(tb, i);
                    Grid.SetRow(tb, j);
                    g.Children.Add(tb);
                }
            }

            return g;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, try this method for a single 200x200 grid with 1 textblock

```
 public Grid buildUIGrid() {
        Grid g = new Grid();

        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(200, GridUnitType.Pixel) });
        g.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(200, GridUnitType.Pixel) });

        int i, j; i = 0; j = 0;
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = "test at col "+i+", row "+j;
        Grid.SetColumn(tb, i);
        Grid.SetRow(tb, j);
        g.Children.Add(tb);

        return g;
    }
```

Please do not generalize, just answer to the given scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the constructor:

```
    public MainPage() {
        //this right here. is the line order wrong?  Tried that. 
        //Is it impossible to do what I want before/after InitializeComponent? 
        //If so, then is there another way to achieve this???
        pgMain = buildUIGrid(); 

        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The XAML file is parsed in the InitializeComponent method (look in your project folders for a file name MainPage.i.g.cs and you'll see that pgMain is set in that method). Before that pgMain is null.

Just move pgMain = buildUIGrid below InitializeComponent:

```
    public MainPage() {

        this.InitializeComponent();
        buildUIGrid(pgMain); 

    }
```

Also update buildUIGrid:

```
public void buildUIGrid(Grid g) {


        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(200, GridUnitType.Pixel) });
        g.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(200, GridUnitType.Pixel) });

        int i, j; i = 0; j = 0;
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = "test at col "+i+", row "+j;
        Grid.SetColumn(tb, i);
        Grid.SetRow(tb, j);
        g.Children.Add(tb);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rui,    
I see there were two issues, one of which I suspected but couldn't confirm because of the second:
1) of course, the order of InitializeComponent(). I need to start the MainPage before making changes to its controls.
2) I needed to _modify_ the existing grid, not assign a new one to it (I still don't understand why, but that's what it seems to be after some tinkering).